# IPhone Simulator - label misaligned

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, uiview, ios-simulator

I have a label sitting on the the top of screen in a tab bar controller app. When I align it to the top of the screen in Interface Builder (IB for short) and then run it, the label is about 20 pixels higher in the simulator - cutting off half the label or so. I have only seen this behaviour in tabbed apps. I have played with all the align, view mode settings without success and there is no custom drawing code.

**Any ideas on why label is misaligned in simulator?**

I have attached screen shots of IB (left - OK) and simulator (right - bad):

[image: OK in IB]
[image: Too high in simulator]

Thanks,
Serge

Comment: hey have you specified bottum bar in your view ?

Comment: Set label's x and y point during run-time programatically...

Comment: post your autosizing configuration

Comment: Let you set status bar hidden or You can also set the y dimension =20 of the label

Comment: PJR - Your comments helped me solve it. The main tab controller simulated metric.bottom set to <none> and the view controller.simulated metrics all set to <inferred> did the trick. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I guess , you are facing problem because of the following reason.
Since Tab area occupies some height from bottom,You have design your view such that top of the label should align with the top of the screen(like label should start by leaving some space (20px something) at the top).

Comment: true, and in Interface Builder, this appears accounted for. All coordinates start at 0,0. I could do that, but then IB would look all wrong as control are all off and only at runtime do they appear correct. This seems to me like a hack. I am after a better solution as I will be doing a lot more of this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **PJR** above for giving the hints. The trick is to setup the 'simulated metrics' of both tab bar controller and each of its first view controllers.
1) The tab bar controller --> simulated metric.bottom bar should be set to none
2) All view controller -->    All simulated metric props set to 'inferred'.

I have provided screen shots for a fresh tabbed project created in Xcode 4.3.1 which show what needs to be done.

[image: tab bar controller setup in IB]
[image: view controller setup in IB]